# HTTP ERROR 500 - Corrupt Customer Account

Tags: magento-1.9

In Manage Customers I have **1** customer account that will not open. The other customer accounts open with no issues.

After clicking the corrupted customer account, I get -

> This page isn’t working is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Can someone tell me how to fix this customer account?  If it cannot be be fixed what's the best way to delete the customer?

I looked in the logs but nothing to see in the logs.

Magento 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by changing the customers Entity ID and Customer ID.  The account now works. Note:  Customer ID and Entity ID are the same ID.